# Maximum of a definite integral

Tags: definite-integrals, holder-inequality

I am required to find

$max\int_{-1}^{1}x^3g(x)dx$

given that

$\int_{-1}^{1}x^ng(x)dx=0$ for $n=0,1,2$ and $\int_{-1}^{1}|g(x)|^2dx=1$.

The hint is to find $\underset{a,b,c}{min}\int_{-1}^{1}|x^3-a-bx-cx^2|^2dx$ first.

Below is what I have found.

$\underset{a,b,c}{min}\int_{-1}^{1}|x^3-a-bx-cx^2|^2dx$ is quite easy.

Let $f(x)=x^3-a-bx-cx^2$, then by Holder's Inequality,

$\int_{-1}^{1}x^{3}g(x)dx\leq \int_{-1}^{1}|f(x)g(x)|dx\leq (\int_{-1}^{1}|f(x)|^2dx)^{\frac{1}{2}}(\int_{-1}^{1}|g(x)|^2dx)^{\frac{1}{2}}=(\int_{-1}^{1}|f(x)|^2dx)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ which has a minimum value from above.

But I am not sure if I am working in the right direction since it seems like I am only able to find an upper bound rather than the maximum value.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried verifying that $f$ satisfies the orthogonality properties verified by $g$ (which should be the case to satisfy the minimum) and replace $g$ by $f$ to have a case of equality in your inequality ?

Comment: What do you mean by the orthogonality properties?

Comment: The fact that $\int_{-1}^1x^if(x)dx = 0$ for $i=0,1,2$.

Comment: How do you know that the max is attained when g is f? Where is the intuition or is this obvious?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you started with
$$f(x)=\frac25P_3(x)+\frac35P_1(x)+c_0P_0(x)+c_1P_1(x)+c_2P_2(x)$$
And found that
$$\int_{-1}^1|f(x)|^2dx=\frac27\left(\frac25\right)^2+\frac25|c_2|^2+\frac23\left|\frac35+c_1\right|^2+\frac21|c_0|^2$$
And so found the minimum value of $\frac8{175}$ then $f(x)=\frac25P_3(x)$. From that point I am assuming that $g(x)$ is also a real function of $x$, else how could you find the maximum of $\int_{-1}^1x^3g(x)dx$?

Let
$$\begin{align}I(\alpha)&=\int_{-1}^1\left(g(x)-\alpha f(x)\right)^2dx\\
&=\int_{-1}^1(g(x))^2dx-2\alpha\int_{-1}^1g(x)f(x)dx+\alpha^2\int_{-1}^1(f(x))^2dx\\
&\ge0\end{align}$$
Then $I(\alpha)$ has a minimum when
$$I^{\prime}(\alpha)=0=-2\int_{-1}^1g(x)f(x)dx+2\alpha\int_{-1}^1(f(x))^2dx$$
So applying this value of $\alpha$,
$$1-\frac{\left[\int_{-1}^1g(x)f(x)dx\right]^2}{\int_{-1}^1(f(x))^2dx}\ge0$$
So that
$$\begin{align}\left[\int_{-1}^1g(x)f(x)dx\right]^2&=\left[\int_{-1}^1g(x)(x^3-a-bx-cx^2)dx\right]^2\\
&=\left[\int_{-1}^1x^3g(x)dx\right]^2\le\int_{-1}^1(f(x))^2dx\end{align}$$
For any real $f(x)=x^3-a-bx-cx^2$, therefore it can be no bigger than the minimum possible value,
$$\left[\int_{-1}^1x^3g(x)dx\right]^2\le\int_{-1}^1\left(\frac25P_3(x)\right)^2dx=\frac4{25}\frac27=\frac8{175}$$
Of course for $g(x)=\sqrt{\frac72}P_3(x)$,
$$\int_{-1}^1(g(x))^2dx=1$$
and
$$\int_{-1}^11\cdot g(x)dx=\int_{-1}^1xg(x)dx=\int_{-1}^1x^2g(x)dx=0$$
And
$$\int_{-1}^1x^3g(x)dx=\int_{-1}^1\frac25P_3(x)\sqrt{\frac72}P_3(x)dx=\frac25\sqrt{\frac27}$$
So the bound is actually attainable.

Comment: What is your $P_{i}(x)$ for $i=0,1,2,3$? I didn’t start of with the same $f$ as yours. I did it by brute force haha. Can you explain your $f(x)$?

Comment: $P_i(x)$ is the [Legendre polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) $$\frac25P_3(x)+\frac35P_1(x)=\frac25\left(\frac52x^3-\frac32x\right)+\frac35\left(x\right)=x^3$$ The orthogonality of the Legendre polynomials made it easy to determine a minimal $f(x)$ once it was expressed in terms of them.

Comment: But I am supposed to do this question in the Hilbert space setting, so can I still use Legendre polynomials?

Comment: $f(x)$ is a polynomial in $x$ of degree $3$, so we chose to express it in terms of the most convenient basis of $\mathcal{P}_3$ for the problem.